# Why do many reference materials mention app icon size 57*57 but not Xcode itself?

Tags: ios, xcode

This web site, and many others, says the app icon for an iPhone should be 57*57
https://www.creativefreedom.co.uk/icon-designers-blog/apple-iphone-and-ipad-app-icon-sizes/

Yet Xcode itself has nothing of this size:
[image]

Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image clearly says `iPhone App, iOS 7-11`. The website you're citing is from 2012 (updated 03/10/2012), iOS 7 came out in September 2013. The website is simply outdated, app icon size was changed in iOS 7.